# QGIS - Working in the attribut formular with Widgets

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, excel, drag-and-drop, qgis-custom-widgets

I want to transform my attribut formular for biotopes to add automatically their value depending on two former columns.
I have an excel table like this:

| Code | rating1 | rating 2 | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | dry | species-rich | 3 |
| A | dry | species-poor | 2 |
| A | wet | species-rich | 4 |
| A | wet | species-poor | 3 |
| B | young | structure-rich | 5 |
| B | young | structure-poor | 4 |
| B | old | structure-rich | 7 |
| B | old | structure-poor | 6 |

The features in my layer are labeld with the "Code"-Column.
So I need the unique value for the features with A and B, depending on the ratings I choose.

What I need is that I can choose "rating1" depending on the "Code" AND then choose "rating2" depending on "rating1" AND then the value for this specific combination of "Code", "rating1" and "rating2" is automatically add.

So "Code" + "rating1" + "rating2" = "value"

I tried a lot with the "Value Map Widget", the "Value Relation Widget" and linking the excel table with the layer.

But problems are:

- I cannot manage to filter in the "Value Map Widget"
- In the "Valure relation widget" I have all the values of rating1 ("dry", "dry", "wet", "wet", etc.)
- by connecting the excel table with the layer I can only choos one column for depending

So any ideas for a good solution?

Comment: I don't get the logic behind the resulting values. Features 1 and 4 are totally different, but get the same value. Why?

Comment: The table I posted is just an example based on an actual rating system for biotops in Germany. A could be a grassland for example. A wet grassland is more valuable than a dry one, but a dry one with more species could reach the same value.

Comment: So you need to list all possible combinations of ratings 1 and 2 and the resulting values in order to assign them automatically.

Comment: But how I get this? When I create a new feature and select Code "A" for this I want to choose in the formular the option for this code for "rating1" and "rating2" to getting the value. When I just combine the excel table with the layer I can only choose one column for Linking.

Comment: Which data does the Excel file represent and why do you deem it necessary?